# "which bundle" and "bundle -v" point at different directories on wsl2; bundle -v does not exist

Tags: ubuntu, bash, ruby, wsl2, bundle

```
$ which bundle
/usr/local/bin/bundle

$ bundle -v
bash: /mnt/c/Ruby26-x64/bin/bundle: No such file or directory
```

I've tried uninstalling and reinstalling bundler; not sure what else to try.

Answer (score 0):

So, I added

```
alias bundle=/usr/local/bin/bundle
```

to my ~/.bash-aliases file. I *think* that worked.

```
$ bundle -v
Bundler version 2.2.25
```